# Angular 2 - simple HTTP GET from component not working

Tags: angularjs, angular, asp.net-web-api2

I have an Angular 2 app that has a simple component (see below).
It makes a simple GET call to a Web Api endpoint.
I can call the end point using postman but when this component tries to it fails. The call is never made and no errors are output.
What have I done wrong? I've followed this pattern before.

```
import { Component, Input }  from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Http,Response, Headers, RequestOptions  } from '@angular/http';
import { DomSanitizationService } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ITile } from '../interfaces/tile';

@Component({
    selector: 'tile',
    template: require('../tile/tile.component.html'),
    styles: [require('../tile/tile.component.css').toString()],

    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class TileComponent {
    @Input() tile: ITile;

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    onSelect(id: string) {
        this.getProfileImage(id);
    }

    getProfileImage(id: string): Observable<string> {

     let url = 'http://localhost:2116/api/profileimage/5/';
     let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.get(url, options)
            .map((response: Response) => <string>response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }

      private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }

}
```

The end point looks like this...

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/profileimage/{userId}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string userId)
{ 
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "success");
}
```

Comment: what is your angular version ?

Comment: "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3"

Comment: How is it failing? Which messages are being shown?

Comment: That's the problem, there is no error output and the endpoint is never reached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the get method (a cold observable) to fire the call.